# Remove item from enum ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums

I have this code here that gets a region and add to my variable "regions".
So let' say it has: XYZ, DDA, BBB, ....
Let's say I want to get everything but DDA.
How can I do that.

Code:

```
def supported_regions(partition)
  if @@supported_regions_by_partition_cache[partition].nil?
    regions = xrp_supported_regions({ignore_build_status: IGNORE_BUILD_STATUS})
      .map { |region| rip_helper.get_region(region) }
      .select { |region| region.arn_partition == partition }
      .sort_by(&:region_name)
      .map(&:airport_code)
    @@supported_regions_by_partition_cache[partition] = regions
  else
    regions = @@supported_regions_by_partition_cache[partition]
  end
  regions
end
```

I already tried doing:

```
regions.delete('DDA')
```

also

```
.reject {|s| 'DDA' != s }
```

Not sure how I can do this. I am very new on Ruby.

Comment: You are already selecting certain regions so you could merely change the criterion: `.select { |region| region.arn_partition == partition && region.name != 'DDA' }`, assuming `name` is the attribute to be compared to `'DDA'`. (It can't be just `region != 'DDA'` as `region` is not a string.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **select** method and replace this line:

FROM

```
      .select { |region| region.arn_partition == partition }
```

TO

```
      .select { |region| region.arn_partition == partition && region.region_name != "DDA" }
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland thanks, you're right. I changed it to `region.region_name` (as in the original, they were sorting based on `region_name`).